# Python error: Cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, directory, subprocess, 7zip

This is my body of code:

```
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Desktop")

rc = subprocess.call(['7z', 'a', 'test', '-y', 'myarchive.zip'] +
                     [r'device teams.txt'])
```

It gives me an error pointing to r'device teams.txt' saying the specified file does not exist.

I checked the directory and it is in the desktop directory so I am not sure why it is giving me this error

Comment: try with `'./device teams.txt'` and check that `"C:\\Users\\Desktop"` is right. For Windows it's usually `"C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop"`

Comment: @bleand Does not work. I edited the path for this purpose to hide any sensitive info. The path is indeed correct and has the username after users. the file is in the correct directory

Comment: I've edited the comment, please check that

Comment: I think the path to desktop skips username, could you pls check that?; Usual path would be C://Users//<username>//Desktop

Comment: I have edited my comment stating the path is correct

Comment: That filename has an embedded space, which often requires careful handling.  Does the error message refer to the full filename, or just to `device`?

Comment: @JohnGordon only refers to this: ['./device teams.txt']). I've also tested with files that have no spaces and it is the same error

Comment: Is that a normal ASCII space in the filename?  Or is it a special unicode space character?

Comment: What are the permissions on the file?  Is it publicly readable?

Comment: @JohnGordon Full read permissions and yes it is a normal ASCII space. I've tested on files with normal characters and the same error appears so I don't think it has anything to do with the naming.

Comment: @AfsheenTaheri can you do `print(os.listdir('.'))` to check if `os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Desktop") `is working? Your file should be printed with all the other files in the directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comments, the problem isn't the `txt` file path, it's that the command `7z` cannot be found. You can check this by just calling `rc = subprocess.call(['7z'])`: the error `The system cannot find the file specified` persists.

Here's how you can achieve the same thing using PowerShell for example:

```
import os
import subprocess
os.chdir("C:\\Users\\Username\\Desktop")
rc = subprocess.call("powershell Compress-Archive -Path 'device teams.txt' -DestinationPath archive.zip")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Just one problem, I need it to be password protected. Any thoughts on how to add that?

Comment: With PowerShell specifically? That's a different question altogether, which you should create a new post for. Any command-line zip utility that supports password protection would work here.

Comment: Preferablly I'd like to keep it in python. I changed 7z to C:\\ProgramData\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start Menu\\Programs\\7-Zip.

Now the error changes to access is denied. I can open 7zip manually with no problems so I'm not sure why I'm receiving the error

Comment: This is a completely separate issue from this post. The issue from this post is resolved. I suggest you create a new post about this.

Comment: I'm confused -- the question clearly said _It gives me an error pointing to r'device teams.txt'_