# Python Creating a 7zip archive with command line

Tags: python, command-line, subprocess, 7zip

So I am trying to run a command line argument to create a 7zip archive as below:

```
rc = subprocess.run([path, 'a', 'archive.7z', '-psecret', 'mhe', 'log.log'])
```

However, all it is doing is opening 7zip and not creating archive.7z as intended.

Any reason why?

Comment: When you say 'opening 7zip' I imagine you mean the file manager GUI, which means you are hitting the wrong executable. You want `7z.exe` not `7zFM.exe` (would be good to include `path` value in question)

Comment: This is might a duplicate of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55838627/8506506

Comment: @CasualDemon Wow thanks this was bugging me for a while

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding comment as answer in case others come across this:

When you say 'opening 7zip' I imagine you mean the file manager GUI, which means you are hitting the wrong executable. You want `path` to end in `7z.exe` not `7zFM.exe`.